# How to determine Preference/Confidence in ALS.transImplicit in Spark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using `trainsimplicit` from `ALS` in Spark.
 From the documentation page: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.ALS.trainImplicit, use `trainImplicit(ratings, rank, iterations=5, lambda_=0.01, blocks=-1, alpha=0.01, nonnegative=False, seed=None)` to train a model.

My question is should we input `ratings` as `(user, product, view times/watching time >0)`?
or `(user, product, preference = 0/1)`?

Meanwhile, I noticed if `alpha =0.01` is changed to other values, the results will be different. How can we know which the preference-confidence relation, like `c = 1 + alpha * r` or `1+ alpha * log(1+r/e)` (`r` could be time duration or number of frequency) is used in Spark during training?

I also noticed, in the web https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.html#ALS.trainImplicit, there is `cls` in the `trainsimplicit` classmethod. Is it a way to define the preference-confidence relation?

A ton of thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the implicit preference is that every time, that user views/watches the product, your confidence is increased. Correct?
Therefore the input should be `(user, product, view times/watching time >0)` 
If you restrict the input to 0/1 preference, you are just loosing information.

As I see from the [original spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala)

```
if (implicitPrefs) {
  // Extension to the original paper to handle b < 0. confidence is a function of |b|
  // instead so that it is never negative. c1 is confidence - 1.0.
  val c1 = alpha * math.abs(rating)
  // For rating <= 0, the corresponding preference is 0. So the term below is only added
  // for rating > 0. Because YtY is already added, we need to adjust the scaling here.
  if (rating > 0) {
    numExplicits += 1
    ls.add(srcFactor, (c1 + 1.0) / c1, c1)
  }
}
```

the ALS uses the modified version of linear dependence.

I never saw any documentation on this though

Comment: I see. But how can we know the ALS uses `confidence = 1+alpha*r` or `confidence = 1+alpha *log(1+r/e)` during training model? Here `r= view times/watching time`, any real number and >0.